# admin portal react front end framework or template

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I am going to create an admin portal website with react.js and I searched about the best/the easiest ways to create it. So far I think [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) and [ant design](https://ant.design/) are good choices to build the site.React-bootstrap does not support bootstrap 4 and seems ant provides more powerful components so I prefer to ant.
Anyone has some other options? or how are your thoughts about ant design?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-admin` framework, a frontend framework for building admin SPAs on top of `REST` services, using React and Material Design. You can find the documentation here - https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [repository](https://github.com/turkogluc/react-admin-portal) which contains the main layout design and reusable components as tables, forms, and charts by using Ant Design and Bizcharts.

You can also find the step by step implementation guide in the [blog post](https://turkogluc.com/developing-react-admin-portal-with-redux-and-ant-design/).